# Computing square root on Delphi

Tags: delphi, math, delphi-7

I need to compute square roots of big numbers (up to 10^100) with setted precission(up to 50 signs after floating point). For this goal I diceded to use the [Digit-by-digit calculation method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Digit-by-digit_calculation). But when I implementing it on Delphi 7  I have many troubles and got confused in my code. Could you show how you would implement this task. Thanks
Here ismy code

```
program sqrtCalc;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$Q+}  {$R+}

uses
  SysUtils,math;

const
  signCount=50; 

var
  inputString:String;
  root:String;
  intString,realString:String;
  intArray,realArray:array of Integer;
  intRootArray,realRootArray:Integer;
  i,j,dotPosition:Integer;
  a,b,c,d:Integer;

Procedure input();
  begin
    WriteLn('x=');
    try
      readln(inputString)
    except
      Writeln('Invalid input data, please try again');
      input(); 
    end;
  end;

begin
  input();
  dotPosition:=pos('.',inputString);
  if dotPosition<>0 then
  begin
    realString:=copy(inputString,dotPosition+1,Length(inputString)-1);
    intString:=copy(inputString,0,dotPosition-1);
    if odd(Length(realString)) then Insert('0',realString,Length(realString)+1);
    i:=1;
    while i<Length(realString) do
    begin
      SetLength(realArray,length(realArray)+1);
      realArray[length(realArray)-1]:=StrToInt(copy(realString,i,2));
      i:=i+2;
     end;
  end
  else
    intString:=inputString;

  if odd(Length(intString)) then Insert('0',intString,1);

  i:=1;
  while i<Length(intString) do
  begin
    SetLength(intArray,length(intArray)+1);
    intArray[length(intArray)-1]:=StrToInt(copy(intString,i,2));
    i:=i+2;
  end;


  //Here must be implementation of mathematic actions
 //But i got confused
  a:=trunc(sqrt(intArray[0])); root:=IntToStr(a);
  b:=intArray[0]-a*a;

  c:=StrToInt(root)*20;
  d:=

  Write(b);
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: No, we won't do your work for you. Show yours first.

Comment: Why don't you show us where you got confused?

Comment: Post your code. This is not a code writing service.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry. I shall edit post

Comment: You say `//Here must be implementation..but I got confused`. What **exactly** is the problem you're having that you are confused about (other than the fact that you convert `a` to a string, assign it to `root`, and then immediately convert `root` back to an integer to multiply with it and assign it to `c`, and you have an invalid `d:=` line of code that won't compile)?

Comment: looking at the algorithm, you have to carry the current result of the root without the decimal point (variable p in wikipedia) and perform arithmetic operations over it, I think it will not be easy to implement in Delphi, for say, up to 10^100 numbers. Int64 (the greater integer is up to 9223372036854775807, so IMHO you're tied to squares with not more than 19 digits (in any part, integer or decimal) if you want to use native types to perform the math.

Answer (score 3):

Use big integer arithmetic instead of strings, either my [TForge](https://bitbucket.org/sergworks/tforge) or Alex Ciobanu's [DeHL](http://code.google.com/p/delphilhlplib/).

If you need 50 digits after decimal point, the argument should be multiplied by 10^100 (exponent value should be even number) to use big cardinal type.

You need to move decimal point 100 position to the right in string representation, convert integer part of the string obtained to big cardinal, use binary algorithm to extract square root from big cardinal value, convert the root to string and move decimal point 50 position left to get final result.

Comment: I didn't know your TForge project, it looks great. The question looks like a programming homework or exam, so maybe the OP have to do using the referred algorithm. I commented the _size_ limitation of Int64 but with TBigInteger I made a quick test and it should work. Even when you don't directly address the question, I give you +1 for that nice work.

Comment: Thanks for kind words, TForge is not completed yet but arithmetic operations passed my tests and should work.